Can hot or cold be defined in an isothermal universe?
Suppose there exists a universe which is exactly isothermal. Can we define hot or cold in such a universe? I guess not. No matter what the temperature is, we cannot define hot or cold. Am I correct?

Define what YOU mean by hot and cold

Hot and cold are physical sensations felt when we touch a hot body or cold body.

How do you define isothermal universe? This is ultimately related to how you define temperature... which makes the Q. a bit circular.

@RogerV. My understanding is that although temperature can not be measured in an isothermal universe but there is a concept of temperature as the particles can have kinetic energy. However I had doubt about the existence of hotness and coldness.

Still, what does it mean, isothermal universe? That the particles always have the same kinetic energy? Or that the energy can be changed only via external work (no heat transfer)? Or that all the statistical distributions have the same $\beta$ parameter?

In an isothermal universe no life or human beings could exist, so there would be no one to "feel" hot or cold sensations

@RogerV. I am not an expert at this. But as I understand the isothermal means the same as in thermodynamics. Temperature as dependent on root mean square velocity of particles. I think temperature can only be defined in statistical sense. It is also said that Universe was nearly isothermal at the beginning of universe. That should give some clue regarding what I mean by isothermal temperature.

@RC_23 This link says universe was extremely hot in the beginning. How was it hot if there was no consciousness? Temperature does exist although we can’t measure it.

@SacrificialEquation But you, in a comment above, defined hot/cold not as temperature but as the physical sensation of temperature. To have a physical sensation you need a living organism to sense it.

@gandalf61 correct me if I am wrong. Hot is hot in the consciousness and no where else. Now the answer says that heat transfer can not take place in an isothermal universe therefore no hot or cold can be felt or physically defined, which is fair enough. I am not sure if I am confusing you but go by your definition of hot and cold. To my surprise even at extremely high isothermal temperatures , hotness and coldness can not be defined if I understood the answer correctly.

Voting to reopen. Nothing non-mainstream here - it is simply a question of definitions.

When we say something we touch feels "hot" or "cold" we're describing our reaction to an increase or decrease in the temperature of our skin as a result of touching something whose temperature is higher or lower than the temperature of our skin prior to touching it.
In your hypothetical world where temperature differences do not exist, the terms become meaningless.
Hope this helps.


Can hot or cold be defined in an isothermal universe ?

If by "hot or cold" you mean the attribute of temperature then the kinetic theory of gases could be used to define the temperature of an ideal gas in such a universe, even if any measurement of such a temperature always gives the same value.
By analogy, any measurement of the speed of light in vacuum always gives the same value in our universe, but that does not prevent us making predictions about hypothetical universes in which the speed of light is not constant.
However, if by "hot or cold" you mean a physical sensation of temperature (as some of your comments suggest) then that requires a living organism to experience that sensation - and no living organism could exist in an isothermal universe, since all life depends on temperature and entropy gradients.
